What is attracting fixed point of a hyperbolic element?
Let $X$ be a hyperbolic metric space.
Let  $\Gamma$ be a finitely generated group. We say $\Gamma$ is hyperbolic if it acts properly and cocompactly on a hyperbolic metric space $X$. We define the $\partial_{\infty} \Gamma  = \partial_{\infty} \text{Cay}(\Gamma, S)$ where $\partial_\infty X$ is the ideal   boundary of $X$.
Now if $\gamma \in \Gamma$ is an infinite order element then there are two fixed points of $\gamma$, namely $\gamma ^+$ and $\gamma ^-$ and follows the north-south dynamics, i.e. if $\{\gamma_i\} \subset \{\gamma^n\mid n\geq 1\}$ is a sequence in $\Gamma$ such that $\gamma_i \rightarrow \gamma ^+$ and $\gamma_i ^{-1}\rightarrow \gamma^{-1}$ then $\forall  z \in \partial\Gamma-\{\gamma^-\}$ we have $ \gamma_i\cdot z \rightarrow \gamma^+$.
But when we should call $\gamma^+$ as attracting fixed point?  How I  prove that $\gamma ^+$  is attracting fixed point? Is the following true?
$\gamma^+$ is the attracting fixed point of $\gamma$ if there exists a sequence $\{\gamma ^n\}$ such that $\gamma^n \cdot x \rightarrow \gamma^+$ for some $x\in \partial\Gamma-\{\gamma^-\}$. I
s it right definition?

Even more, you have uniform convergence on compacts on the complement to the repelling fixed point in $X\cup \partial X$.
